# If $f$ is continuous and non-negative, then $\inf (f)^2=\inf (f^2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I think that the following conjecture is true and I tried to proved as follows:

> For any non-negative continuous function $f$ on $\left [ a,b \right ]$, let  $m(f)=\inf \left \{ f(t) : a\leq t\leq b  \right \}$. Then $m(f)^{2}=m(f^2)$.

My try to prove this:

Since $f$ is continuous on $\left [ a,b \right ]$, then $f$ has a minimum value, called $f(d)$ for some $d \in \left [ a,b \right ]$, therefore $m(f)^{2}=f(d)^{2}$.

Now, since $f$ is continuous, then $f^2$ is continuous and it admits a minimum value on $\left [ a,b \right ]$, called $f({d}')^{2}$, but then we have that $f(x)^{2}\geq f({d}')^{2}$ which implies $(f(x)+f(d'))(f(x)-f(d'))\geq 0$. But since $f$ is non-negative, $(f(x)+f(d'))\geq 0$, this implies that $f(x)-f(d')\geq 0$ for all $x$ on  $\left [ a,b \right ]$. This means that $f(d')$ is a minimum value of $f$, therefore $f(d')=f(d)$ and $m(f)^{2}=m(f^2)$.

Is this aproach correct?

Comment: MathJax tip: replace `inf` with `\inf`. It looks much better (especially with the hideous kerning around $f$).

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: This should also be true for $f$ bounded and non-negative. Continuity is redundant.

Comment: This is good! It might be slightly more clean to prove that, if $a,b\ge0$, then $a \le b \iff a^2 \le b^2$, as a lemma. This is essentially what you did with the difference of two squares thing. Then you can say that $f(d’)^2 \le f(d)^2 \implies f(d’) \le f(d)$, so $f(d’)=f(d)$. When your proof relies on a more generally useful fact, it’s usually considered more elegant to prove this fact separately, rather than squeezing it all into one proof. But, this is a stylistic pointer, and again, your proof is solid.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems correct to me, but we should be able to prove the same will hold without the continuity restriction. Here's how I would frame the proof:

Let's suppose that there is such an $f$ such that $f(x) \geq 0$ on $[a,b]$ with $\inf_{[a, b]} f(x) = m$ but $\inf_{[a, b]} f(x)^2 \neq m^2.$ This implies that either there is some $t \in [a, b]$ such that $f(t)^2 \leq m^2,$ or that there is some tigher lower bound $n^2 > m^2$ such that $f(x)^2 \leq n^2$ for all $x \in [a,b].$

Regarding the first case, because the square root function is monotone decreasing we have that $f(t)^2 \leq m^2$ implies that $|f(t)| \leq |m|,$ and because both $f(t)$ and $m$ must be positive (if $m$ was negative then $0$ would be a tighter lower bound) this implies that $f(t) \leq m,$ which contradicts the definition of $m$ as a lower bound.

For the second case, similarly we have that $f(x)^2 \leq n^2$ implies that $f(x) \leq n$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ for some $n > m,$ which also contradicts the fact that $m$ is the infimum of $f(x)$ because it forms a tighter lower bound.

So, because $m^2$ is the highest possible lower bound of $f^2,$ it is the infimum of $f^2.$

(Note: your manipulation involving the difference of squares will also work in either case)

The non-negative condition cannot be dropped, as evidenced by the case of a function like $x^3$ on $[-1, 1],$ where $(\inf_{[-1, 1]} x^3)^2 = (-1)^2 = 1$ but $\inf_{[-1, 1]} (x^3)^2 = \inf_{[-1, 1]} x^6 = 0.$